# Android single- and multi-stroke gestures in the same library confuses the GesturesOverlayView?

Tags: android, gestures

I have noticed a problem on various handsets that if you save gestures while the stroketype is set to single and then change the stroketype to multi and add some multi-stroke gestures, the multi ones are often not recognized by the GesturesOverlayView when you draw them. These can be very simple gestures such as a + or an X. What happens is that the gesture you draw stays faded as if it has not been recognized even though it can be a perfect match.

I know that multi-stroke works okay so I am wondering if the problem is caused by having mixed ones in the library and changing the stroke-type of the view on the fly. Is it possibly confusing it with a single-stroke gesture in the same library but because the match is not close enough, just giving up?

Has anyone had a similar experience or a theory as to what might be happening?

Comment: Yes I'm having the same problem, and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Will this also happen if the single and the multi strokes gestures a completly different? Like making and x for double and a - for single?

Comment: Sorry, I never got to the bottom of this - I just noted the symptoms but didn't both pursuing it because it was an edge-case for me.

Answer (score 1):

check   android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold ="15.2"

android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
and

android:fadeOffset="6000"

Comment: Thanks. I am no longer working on this code but if I go back to it, I will do what you say and test it. Which is why I can't mark the answer as correct.